# Deploy React with Nginx failed to load resources

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I'm trying to deploy a react app with nginx reverse proxy.

My server configuration block (/etc/nginx/sites-available/app2.conf) is as follow:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen[::]:80;
  root/srv/app2/build;
  index index.html index.html;
  server_name _;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

I'm using a docker to run the react app with port 3001 exposed. 
I tried to use curl to see if it works. The curl command works as expected.

```
curl http://localhost:3001
```

However, when i tried to run in my web browser i got the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.8ea061ea.chunk.css
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) main.dcd07bc1.chunk.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) 1.a6f3a221.chunk.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) main.dcd07bc1.chunk.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) main.8ea061ea.chunk.css

It seems that it failed to load all the static files (.css & .js) files. 
Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: what's the request url of your nginx server and your upstream server

Comment: Are we using express server on frontend?

Comment: Could you post the complete URL for the css files which your browser is trying to fetch? You can try to curl those requests and see what is the response.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/

You have to specify the way static files are to served depending upon the url requested for static files.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

try using this config to build the docker

```
# build environment
FROM node:9.6.1 as builder
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g --silent
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

never had any problem using this script. U might miss some nginx config or forgot to copy recursively, who knows if u didnt post the Dockerfile

*note: i didnt make it
credit: https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an elegant solution for nginx reverse proxy cofiguration.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/app2.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;

            # recommended settings
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Don't forget symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/app2.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```